# avoid manually refresh entity to get Dtype from newly created entities

Tags: jakarta-ee, entity, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I have a some entities inheriting an AbstractEntity like below.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String dtype;

    public String getDtype() {
        return dtype;
    }
}
```

Then I persist some entity that extends AbstractEntity.

```
ConcreteEntity concreteEntity = new ConcreteEntity();
em.persist(concreteEntity);
```

If then in some other ejb fetch this entity using

```
someEntity = query.getResultList().get(0);
```

the instance returned will have `dtype == null` until

```
em.refresh(someEntity);
```

I guess this is because the entity manager returns a cached instance that doesnt know which dtype was inserted on em.persist().

But my question is how can I have the query return instances where dtype is set?

Im using glassfish 3.1.2.2 (default jpa provider and the included javadb)

Comment: i was using it in jsf facelets. #{entity.dtype == 'ConcreteEntity'} Basically i fetch a list of the abstract entities, then display them differently depending on type. Perhaps there are other approaches to this problem

Comment: yepp, that worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even need it? `dtype` is an internal implementation detail needed by ORM. You can simply use Java type to distinguish between subclasses. E.g. in Facelets context you can try `.getClass().getSimpleName()`:

```
#{entity.class.simpleName == 'ConcreteEntity'}
```

Not entirely cleaner, but works.